# How to create this SAML response in C#

Tags: c#, xml, saml

How can I create this XML in C#. Is there any nuget package to create this SAML:Reponse?

I tried following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56640/Performing-a-SAML-Post-with-C.

Also tried to follow [Working with SAML 2.0 in C# .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530184/working-with-saml-2-0-in-c-sharp-net-4-5)

But I am not able to make the following xml format.

```
    <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_8e8dc5f69a98cc4c1ff3427e5ce34606fd672f91e6" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" Destination="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685">
      <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
      <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
      </samlp:Status>
      <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_d71a3a8e9fcc45c9e9d248ef7049393fc8f04e5f75" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z">
        <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
          <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">_ce3d2948b4cf20146dee0a0b3dd6f69b6cf86f62d7</saml:NameID>
          <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z" Recipient="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685"/>
          </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-17T01:01:18Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z">
          <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Audience>
          </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2024-07-17T09:01:48Z" SessionIndex="_be9967abd904ddcae3c0eb4189adbe3f71e327cf93">
          <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
          </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
          <saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
          </saml:Attribute>
          <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
          </saml:Attribute>
          <saml:Attribute Name="eduPersonAffiliation" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">users</saml:AttributeValue>
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">examplerole1</saml:AttributeValue>
          </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
      </saml:Assertion>
    </samlp:Response>
```

Comment: what were you able to produce and what exactly weren't you able to?