# Support for SAML within .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml

Are there any inbuilt .Net libraries which Microsoft ship within .Net framework to build SP-Initiated Authentication. 
If yes please let me know the reference.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530184/working-with-saml-2-0-in-c-sharp-net-4-5).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list:

- [ComponentSpace](http://www.componentspace.com/) (commercial)
- [OIOSAML](https://digitaliser.dk/resource/2972745) (open source)
- [ITfoxtec](http://itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) (open source)
- [Kentor](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) (open source)
- [Owin.Security.Saml](https://github.com/elerch/SAML2) (open source)