# Syntax error while generating SAML Token

Tags: c#, xml, soap, saml-2.0

This is related to my earlier question:
[SAML Assertion in a XML using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp)

The `<saml2:Issuer>` tag is still ending after the `<Signature>` whereas it should be

`<saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509Subjec‌​‌​tName">CN=SAML User,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=Los Angeles,ST=CA,C=US</saml2:Issuer>`

Also I need help on creating the `<saml2:Subject> </saml2:Subject>` part which should come after the `</Signature>` and need to add the Signature Key value inside the `<saml2:Subject> </saml2:Subject>` tag. Please check the Desired output mentioned in my earlier post. Can anyone help me on this?

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Certificate
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"D:\Certificate\ITI55.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            CreateSoap(doc);
            XmlElement issuer = (XmlElement)(doc.GetElementsByTagName("saml2:Issuer")[0]);
            XmlElement body = (XmlElement)(doc.GetElementsByTagName("soap:Body")[0]);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                byte[] xmlBytes = client.DownloadData(FILENAME);
                body.InnerXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlBytes);
            }
            string pfxpath = @"D:\Certificate\Test-cert.pfx";
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pfxpath),"123456789");
            SignXmlWithCertificate(issuer, cert);

            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Certificate\digitallysigned.xml",doc.OuterXml);
        }
        public static void CreateSoap(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string soap = string.Format(
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                "<soap:Envelope" +
                " xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"" +
                " xmlns:wsse11=\"http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd\"" +
                " xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\"" +
                " xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"" +
                " xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                " xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"" +
                " xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion\"" +
                " xmlns:exc14n=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\">" +

                           "<soap:Header>" +
                                  "<To mustUnderstand=\"true\"" +
                                     " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">https://localhost:443/Gateway/PatientDiscovery/1_0/NwHINService/NwHINPatientDiscovery" +
                                  "</To>" +
                                  "<Action mustUnderstand=\"true\"" +
                                     " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">urn:hl7-org:v3:PRPA_IN201305UV02:CrossGatewayPatientDiscovery" +
                                  "</Action>" +
                                  "<ReplyTo mustUnderstand=\"true\"" +
                                     " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">" +
                                     "<Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>" +
                                  "</ReplyTo>" +
                                  "<MessageID mustUnderstand=\"true\"" +
                                     " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">461433e3-4591-453b-9eb6-791c7f5ff882" +
                                  "</MessageID>" +
                                  "<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand=\"true\">" +
                                     "<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id=\"_1\"" +
                                        " xmlns:ns17=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/wssecureconversation/200512\"" +
                                        " xmlns:ns16=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                                        "<wsu:Created>2012-06-08T18:31:44Z</wsu:Created>" +
                                        "<wsu:Expires>2012-06-08T18:36:44Z</wsu:Expires>" +
                                     "</wsu:Timestamp>" +
                                     "<saml2:Assertion ID=\"_883e64a747a5449b83821913a2b189e6\" IssueInstant=\"{0}\" Version=\"2.0\"" +
                                        " xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"" +
                                        " xmlns:exc14n=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-excc14n#\"" +
                                        " xmlns:saml2=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"" +
                                        " xmlns:xenc=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#\"" +
                                        " xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                                        "<saml2:Issuer Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName\">CN=SAML User,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=Los Angeles,ST=CA,C=US" +
                                        "</saml2:Issuer>" +
                                     "</saml2:Assertion>" +
                                  "</wsse:Security>" +
                                "</soap:Header>" +
                                "<soap:Body>" +
                                "</soap:Body>" +
                             "</soap:Envelope>",
                             date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"));
            doc.LoadXml(soap);
        }
        public static void SignXmlWithCertificate(XmlElement doc, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
            signedXml.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlsig = signedXml.GetXml();

            doc.AppendChild(xmlsig);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
    xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <soap:Header>
        <To mustUnderstand="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://localhost:443/Gateway/PatientDiscovery/1_0/NwHINService/NwHINPatientDiscovery
        </To>
        <Action mustUnderstand="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:hl7-org:v3:PRPA_IN201305UV02:CrossGatewayPatientDiscovery
        </Action>
        <ReplyTo mustUnderstand="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
        <MessageID mustUnderstand="true"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">461433e3-4591-453b-9eb6-791c7f5ff882
        </MessageID>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="_1"
                xmlns:ns17="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/wssecureconversation/200512"
                xmlns:ns16="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <wsu:Created>2012-06-08T18:31:44Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2012-06-08T18:36:44Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <saml2:Assertion ID="_883e64a747a5449b83821913a2b189e6" IssueInstant="2017-10-17T04:42:15.609Z" Version="2.0"
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                xmlns:exc14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-excc14n#"
                xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName">CN=SAML User,OU=SU,O=SAML User,L=Los Angeles,ST=CA,C=US
                    <Signature
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <SignedInfo>
                            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                            <Reference URI="">
                                <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                </Transforms>
                                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                                <DigestValue>Y4fQlgQom4UCIcQf09L17JAUnvE=</DigestValue>
                            </Reference>
                        </SignedInfo>
                        <SignatureValue>Zcd+kYVve4/Qq4BiacvG05d5sHo9Td9W3VpmtuXWOgElwnmZnkGd1cRrKrElAqs6Xe9zaLFFW0Y047Wv0dPWN/zCEPsvBKLI6cMZUkV3kM9jM8NsKrE+7UKBs8QRFKPTsEPBdNuK0uoc0dhAYS6kIHz015cte1ciMqkvSoYmBUb+Bn+nOzVMAiOzCsUmCnj8uTZuuP2FV2yGAlanOUmOPjeDVs5M9ZMjQ7pfrkp9NWtDPaXmafcEZ6IT3VTKcNEGbKD/3uL3YywUxNEIGNzen1YRqo3kLOYT3IPizbl0FFi5LtwefCxVEOUohYZuDG8lGMwmkzOT5TQMObQyIpESUw==</SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo>
                            <X509Data>
                                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                            </X509Data>
                        </KeyInfo>
                    </Signature>
                </saml2:Issuer>
            </saml2:Assertion>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <PRPA_IN201305UV02
            xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            xmlns:ns2="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:nhinccommon"
            xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:ns4="urn:gov:hhs:fha:nhinc:common:patientcorrelationfacade"
            xmlns:ns5="http://www.hhs.gov/healthit/nhin"
            xmlns:ns6="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0"
            xmlns:ns7="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0"
            xmlns:ns8="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" ITSVersion="XML_1.0" nullFlavor="">
            <id extension="50a6fe29-cfd5-45ef-8cbe-67e567c9a23c" nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.30" />
            <creationTime nullFlavor="" value="20150309171201" />
            <interactionId extension="PRPA_IN201305UV02" nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6" />
            <processingCode code="T" nullFlavor="" />
            <processingModeCode code="T" nullFlavor="" />
            <acceptAckCode code="NE" nullFlavor="" />
            <receiver typeCode="RCV">
                <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                    <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.1259.10.1003" />
                    <asAgent classCode="AGNT">
                        <representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
                            <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.1259.10.1003" />
                        </representedOrganization>
                    </asAgent>
                </device>
            </receiver>
            <sender nullFlavor="" typeCode="SND">
                <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE" nullFlavor="">
                    <id nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.30" />
                    <asAgent classCode="AGNT" nullFlavor="">
                        <representedOrganization classCode="ORG" determinerCode="INSTANCE" nullFlavor="">
                            <id nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.30" />
                        </representedOrganization>
                    </asAgent>
                </device>
            </sender>
            <controlActProcess classCode="CACT" moodCode="EVN" nullFlavor="">
                <code code="PRPA_TE201305UV02" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6" nullFlavor="" />
                <authorOrPerformer nullFlavor="" typeCode="AUT">
                    <assignedDevice classCode="ASSIGNED" nullFlavor="">
                        <id nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.50" />
                    </assignedDevice>
                </authorOrPerformer>
                <queryByParameter nullFlavor="">
                    <queryId extension="ee72b41a-4eb6-4eb0-ab74-0d4ea29dd1b2" nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.30" />
                    <statusCode code="new" nullFlavor="" />
                    <responseModalityCode code="R" nullFlavor="" />
                    <responsePriorityCode code="I" nullFlavor="" />
                    <parameterList nullFlavor="">
                        <livingSubjectAdministrativeGender nullFlavor="">
                            <value code="M" nullFlavor="" />
                            <semanticsText nullFlavor="" />
                        </livingSubjectAdministrativeGender>
                        <livingSubjectBirthTime nullFlavor="">
                            <value nullFlavor="" value="19600210" />
                            <semanticsText nullFlavor="" />
                        </livingSubjectBirthTime>
                        <livingSubjectId nullFlavor="">
                            <value extension="1000131023" nullFlavor="" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.89.102.15.50" />
                            <semanticsText nullFlavor="" />
                        </livingSubjectId>
                        <livingSubjectName nullFlavor="">
                            <value nullFlavor="" use="">
                                <given partType="GIV" qualifier="">Robert</given>
                                <given partType="GIV" qualifier="">M</given>
                                <family partType="FAM" qualifier="">Carson</family>
                            </value>
                            <semanticsText nullFlavor="" />
                        </livingSubjectName>
                    </parameterList>
                </queryByParameter>
            </controlActProcess>
        </PRPA_IN201305UV02>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Answer in duplicate posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp.  Signature should be a child of assertion and not a child of issuer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating the SAML token like this (which is not very dynamic), why not use the built in .Net library WIF to create the assertion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.saml2.saml2assertion.aspx. 
You can generate XML of the assertion generated by this as stated in this answer: [Working with SAML 2.0 in C# .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530184/working-with-saml-2-0-in-c-sharp-net-4-5)
Or better, why not use some third party libraries like Component Space (https://www.componentspace.com/) which are really easy to use?